# Remove white space from contact number fetched from phone book

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring

I know its a very basic question, but I am stuck at this point.

I am fetching contact numbers from phonebook and having them in an array.

And then fetching a particular one from array in NSString

And I am trying to remove white space from the number, but it is not actually with the below written codes:

```
NSString *num = @"+44 123 456 7890";

num = [num stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"0"];

**OR**

num = [num stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Please let me know what I need to do to remove this space.

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
NSString *num = [contactNumbers objectAtIndex:i];
        num = [num stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
        num = [num stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        num = [num substringFromIndex:[num length]-10];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Done the trick :

```
NSString * strippedNumber = [num stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^0-9]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [number length])];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Replace @"0" with @""
num = [num stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Using `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` only trims white spaces from the beginning and end of string.

**EDIT**

```
NSString *num = [contactNumbers objectAtIndex:i];
NSString *newString = [num stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
newString = [newString substringFromIndex:[num length]-10];
```

Comment: @DeepK It should work on a NSString. Unless the code you showed is not actually what you have. Then, I will ask that you show them in order for people to help you.

Comment: Even I dont want to add 0, I am doing it for the testing sake, but it is not even adding 0 as well, Please see the edit part

Comment: Why not use NSLog after each operation and show your result?

Comment: Showing the same result

Comment: Sorry Not Working, again same result : +44 123 456 7890